# Singleton Detection in Linear Time [Prolog Variables]

Tags: prolog, time-complexity, data-sharing

[More](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_singletons/2) and [more](https://github.com/trealla-prolog/trealla) Prolog systems support the built-in
`term_singletons/2` which gives a list of the singleton
variables of a Prolog term. Unfortunately because of

term sharing in a Prolog term, many algorithms are not
linear in the number of nodes of the Prolog term. One
can observe a kind of explosion:

```
/* SWI-Prolog 9.1.16 */
bomb(0, 1) :- !.
bomb(N, (X+X)) :- M is N-1, bomb(M, X)

?- between(23,27,N), bomb(N,X),
    time(term_singletons(X,_)), fail; true.
% -1 inferences, 0.078 CPU in 0.074 seconds (106% CPU, -13 Lips)
% -1 inferences, 0.141 CPU in 0.153 seconds (92% CPU, -7 Lips)
% -1 inferences, 0.328 CPU in 0.322 seconds (102% CPU, -3 Lips)
% -1 inferences, 0.672 CPU in 0.667 seconds (101% CPU, -1 Lips)
% -1 inferences, 1.344 CPU in 1.350 seconds (100% CPU, -1 Lips)
true.
```

How would one implement `term_singletons/2` that stays
linear in the above case?

Comment: How is it implemented now?

Comment: *More and more Prolog systems*: Which systems?

Comment: Which *three other Prolog systems*?

Comment: I have edited the post. You can click on the words _more_ now, to see two examples of Prolog systems that have term_singletons/2. Following these links, one can also figure how the built-in is implemented.

Comment: *not linear in the number of nodes* SWI even produces a representation error for rational trees.